# Solution Verification: Factoring $\left|\begin{smallmatrix}x&y&z\\x^p&y^p&z^p\\x^{p^2}&y^{p^2}&z^{p^2}\end{smallmatrix}\right|$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p.$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, finite-fields, factoring

> Problem: Factor $\begin{vmatrix} x & y & z \\ x^p & y^p & z^p \\
> x^{p^2} & y^{p^2} & z^{p^2} \end{vmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a
> product of polynomials of the form $ax+by+cz$ with $a,b,c$ constants.

My solution: The determinant can be treated as a polynomial of degree $p^2$ in $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p[y,z].$ If $x=ay+bz,$ then $x^p = (ay+bz)^p \equiv a^p z^p + b^p z^p \equiv az^p + bz^p \mod p$ and $x^{p^2} = (x^p)^p \equiv (az^p+bz^p)^p \equiv az^{p^2} + by^{p^2} \mod p$ similarly, so $$\begin{vmatrix} x & y & z \\ x^p & y^p & z^p \\
x^{p^2} & y^{p^2} & z^{p^2} \end{vmatrix} \equiv \begin{vmatrix} x & y & z \\ ay^p+bz^p & y^p & z^p \\
ax^{p^2}+by^{p^2} & y^{p^2} & z^{p^2} \end{vmatrix} = 0 \mod p.$$ Thus, the polynomial is divisible by $x-ay-bz$ for $0 \le a, b < p.$ This leads to $p^2$ factors, so we have accounted for all the factors of the polynomial and it remains to factor the leading coefficient, which is $\begin{vmatrix} y & z \\ y^p & z^p\end{vmatrix}.$ Similarly, we can treat this as a degree $p$ polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p[z]$ and find that the determinant is $0 \mod p$ when $y=az,$ so $y-az$ is a factor for $0 \le a < p.$ This accounts for all $p$ factors, and the leading coefficient is $-z,$ finally leading to the factorization $$-z\prod\limits_{k=0}^{p-1} (y-kz) \prod\limits_{0 \le i,j < p} (x-iy-jz).$$

This problem appeared on the Putnam, which is known for strict grading, so I wish to be careful that no major details are left out. During the competition, $17$ people solved (8,9 or 10 points) this problem and $34$ people attempted (0,1, or 2 points) it unsuccessfully. This leads me to believe that lots of people who thought they solved the problem were mistaken. If this solution is valid, how did 2/3 competitors who wrote down something mess up their solution?

Comment: The hard part, I think, involves being careful about whether you've actually checked for divisibility. You say "the determinant can be treated as a polynomial... in $x$" but you don't say what the coefficients of this polynomial are; are they elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ or elements of $\mathbb{F}_p[y, z]$ or elements of $\mathbb{F}_p(y, z)$ or what?

Comment: I discuss this problem in a very old blog post of mine (from when I was a teenager), it's possible to work symmetrically in $x, y, z$:  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1157h990757_the_magic_of_the_frobenius_map

Comment: Only me seing $x^p$ recalls Little Fermat's theorem of $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ (forgetting to mention $(x,p)=1$)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I clarified that the coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_p[y,z]$ and then $\mathbb{F}_p[z].$ Is the solution fine now?

Comment: There's still something to be careful about. You say "if $x = ay + bz$ but where is this equality taking place? Certainly not in $\mathbb{F}_p[x, y, z]$ right? In my blog post I deal with this issue by working in the quotient $\mathbb{F}_p[x, y, z]/(ax + by + cz)$ for $a, b, c$ not all zero which deals with all the factors at once. In this quotient $ax + by + cz = 0$ and applying Frobenius twice gives $ax^p + by^p + cz^p = 0$ and $ax^{p^2} + by^{p^2} + cz^{p^2} = 0$ so the determinant vanishes in this quotient.

Answer (score 1):

I get the determinant to be the negative of yours. If you look at the coefficient
of $x^{p^2}y^pz$ in your solution, it is $1$ but in the determinant it is $-1$.

Anyway, the determinant is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p^2+p+1$.
I claim that every linear form $ax+by+cz$ with $(a,b,c)$ a nonzero vector over
$\Bbb Z_p$ is a factor of the determinant. You can prove it your way, or observe that
if $ax+by+cz=0$ in a field of characteristic $p$, then
$ax^p+by^p+cz^p=0$ and $ax^{p^2}+by^{p^2}+cz^{p^2}=0$ so that $(a.b.c)^t$ is in the nullspace of the matrix.